# spatial mdx date aggregation function is not working with date like 01/01/2014

Tags: analytics, mdx, mondrian, olap4j, data-cube

This is my `mdx` that is emitting error:

```
`with member [Measures].[incident_type] as '[incident].CurrentMember.Properties("incident_type")'
  member [Measures].[incident_desc] as '[incident].CurrentMember.Properties("incident_desc")'
  member [Measures].[incident_class] as '[incident].CurrentMember.Properties("incident_class")'
  member [Measures].[incident_image] as '[incident].CurrentMember.Properties("incident_image")'
  member [Measures].[modus_operandi] as '[incident].CurrentMember.Properties("modus_operandi")'
  member [Measures].[fir_status] as '[incident].CurrentMember.Properties("fir_status")'
  member [Measures].[fir_id] as '[incident].CurrentMember.Properties("fir_id")'
  member [Measures].[date_start_time] as '[incident].CurrentMember.Properties("date_start_time")'
  member [Measures].[the_geom] as '[incident].CurrentMember.Properties("the_geom")'
  member [Measures].[date_end_time] as '[incident].CurrentMember.Properties("date_end_time")'
   member [time].[newtime] as 'Aggregate({([time].[2012].[12].[19] : [time].[2012].[12].[31]),([time].[2013]),([time].[2014].[1].[1] : [time].[2014].[1].[8])})'
select {[Measures].[incident_type], [Measures].[incident_desc], [Measures].[incident_class], [Measures].[incident_image], [Measures].[modus_operandi], [Measures].[fir_status], [Measures].[fir_id],  [Measures].[the_geom], [Measures].[date_start_time] ,[Measures].[date_end_time] ,  [Measures].[incident_count]} ON COLUMNS,NON EMPTY Filter([incident].[incident_id].Members, ST_Contains([district].[district_id].[13221].Properties("the_geom"), [incident].CurrentMember.Properties("the_geom"))) ON ROWS  from [pin_mapping]  where ([time].[newtime])`
```

I am testing it on geomondrian workbench which is showing this error as below:

> `Mondrian Error:Failed to parse query 'with member
>   [Measures].[incident_type] as
>   '[incident].CurrentMember.Properties("incident_type")'   member
>   [Measures].[incident_desc] as
>   '[incident].CurrentMember.Properties("incident_desc")'   member
>   [Measures].[incident_class] as
>   '[incident].CurrentMember.Properties("incident_class")'   member
>   [Measures].[incident_image] as
>   '[incident].CurrentMember.Properties("incident_image")'   member
>   [Measures].[modus_operandi] as
>   '[incident].CurrentMember.Properties("modus_operandi")'   member
>   [Measures].[fir_status] as
>   '[incident].CurrentMember.Properties("fir_status")'   member
>   [Measures].[fir_id] as '[incident].CurrentMember.Properties("fir_id")'
>   member [Measures].[date_start_time] as
>   '[incident].CurrentMember.Properties("date_start_time")'   member
>   [Measures].[the_geom] as
>   '[incident].CurrentMember.Properties("the_geom")'   member
>   [Measures].[date_end_time] as
>   '[incident].CurrentMember.Properties("date_end_time")'    member
>   [time].[newtime] as 'Aggregate({([time].[2012].[12].[19] :
>   [time].[2012].[12].[31]),([time].[2013]),([time].[2014].[1].[1] :
>   [time].[2014].[1].[8])})' select {[Measures].[incident_type],
>   [Measures].[incident_desc], [Measures].[incident_class],
>   [Measures].[incident_image], [Measures].[modus_operandi],
>   [Measures].[fir_status], [Measures].[fir_id],  [Measures].[the_geom],
>   [Measures].[date_start_time] ,[Measures].[date_end_time] , 
>   [Measures].[incident_count]} ON COLUMNS,NON EMPTY
>   Filter([incident].[incident_id].Members,
>   ST_Contains([district].[district_id].[13221].Properties("the_geom"),
>   [incident].CurrentMember.Properties("the_geom"))) ON ROWS  from
>   [pin_mapping]  where ([time].[newtime])'
>
> `Mondrian Error:Error while parsing MDX statement 'with member
>   [Measures].[incident_type] as
>   '[incident].CurrentMember.Properties("incident_type")'   member
>   [Measures].[incident_desc] as
>   '[incident].CurrentMember.Properties("incident_desc")'   member
>   [Measures].[incident_class] as
>   '[incident].CurrentMember.Properties("incident_class")'   member
>   [Measures].[incident_image] as
>   '[incident].CurrentMember.Properties("incident_image")'   member
>   [Measures].[modus_operandi] as
>   '[incident].CurrentMember.Properties("modus_operandi")'   member
>   [Measures].[fir_status] as
>   '[incident].CurrentMember.Properties("fir_status")'   member
>   [Measures].[fir_id] as '[incident].CurrentMember.Properties("fir_id")'
>   member [Measures].[date_start_time] as
>   '[incident].CurrentMember.Properties("date_start_time")'   member
>   [Measures].[the_geom] as
>   '[incident].CurrentMember.Properties("the_geom")'   member
>   [Measures].[date_end_time] as
>   '[incident].CurrentMember.Properties("date_end_time")'    member
>   [time].[newtime] as 'Aggregate({([time].[2012].[12].[19] :
>   [time].[2012].[12].[31]),([time].[2013]),([time].[2014].[1].[1] :
>   [time].[2014].[1].[8])})' select {[Measures].[incident_type],
>   [Measures].[incident_desc], [Measures].[incident_class],
>   [Measures].[incident_image], [Measures].[modus_operandi],
>   [Measures].[fir_status], [Measures].[fir_id],  [Measures].[the_geom],
>   [Measures].[date_start_time] ,[Measures].[date_end_time] , 
>   [Measures].[incident_count]} ON COLUMNS,NON EMPTY
>   Filter([incident].[incident_id].Members,
>   ST_Contains([district].[district_id].[13221].Properties("the_geom"),
>   [incident].CurrentMember.Properties("the_geom"))) ON ROWS  from
>   [pin_mapping]  where ([time].[newtime])'

Mondrian Error:MDX object '[time].[2014].[1].[1]' not found in cube 'pin_mapping']`

What is the reason for this error?

Answer (score 0):

Try changing `[time].[2014].[1].[1]` to a member that exists in the cube. Do you still get the same error?

If you do a range with `:` and either the left or right side member does not exist then the engine will evaluate this member as `null`

Comment: but in calender table which i am referring as the time dimension has this date 01-01-2014 and in data cube i also has the dimension time which has the level i.e. year,month and day..so i think the member exists in the cube..

Comment: @RanjeetPaswan I would start by simplifying your script to a very simple script that works - then gradually add back bits of the scipt until you find the problem.